# How hide the validation error first moment for passwordbox wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I try to realize the password box data validation in my WPF page. 
I use MVVM Light in my project.

1) I have the ViewModel where I realized the `IDataErrorInfo` by data annotation

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email field should be filled in")]
[RegularExpression(@"(^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(.{8,100})$)", ErrorMessage = ("Password must have minimum 8 characters, at least one number and one capitalized letter"))]
public string Password
{
    get => _password;
    set => Set(ref _password, value);
}
```

and interface implementation

```
#region Validation configure
    public string Error => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Password":
                    string passwordError = ValidateModelProperty(Password, columnName);
                    return passwordError;
            }

            return error;
        }
    }

    private string ValidateModelProperty(object value, string propertyName)
    {
        ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };
        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, validationContext, validationResults))
            foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
                return validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        return null;
    }
    #endregion
```

2) I sent the password value in the background code

```
protected SignInViewModel Context => DataContext as SignInViewModel;

private void Password_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Context.Password = password.Password;
}
```

In MVVM light realization of the context implement by ServiceLocator in `ViewModelLocator`

```
public SignInViewModel SignInContext => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SignInViewModel>();
```

that's work fine, I take the data of password in ViewModel

3) XAML

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="password" 
                         PasswordChanged="Password_PasswordChanged"  
                         materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Password" 
                         Margin="0,0,0,20"
                         Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}" 

                         FontSize="18" 
                         Foreground="RoyalBlue" 
                         FontWeight="Heavy">
                <PasswordBox.Tag>
                    <Binding  Mode="OneWay" Path="Password" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </PasswordBox.Tag>
            </PasswordBox>
```

here I try to bind the `Tag` to show the error message under the `PasswordBox`. 
But if the parameters are `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"`. I have the problem with the error message, which shows when the page opens in the first time. However, the validation is work!! (it should show when I write the value in the password box)

If I choose `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"` the validation isn't working. The data send to VM but I don't have the error message when I write the value in the password box.

I want to realize the logic when the page open I have clear form when I write the data I can see the validation error under the password box. How fix that moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First load of validation Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MngZ4.png)

You can simply add a Flag when it is a first load. 
Like this

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
  var validResult = new ValidationResult(true, string.Empty);
  if (IsFirstLoad)
  {
    IsFirstLoad = false;
    return validResult;
  }
}
```